# Не знаю как сделать так чтобы бот сохранял в файл txt определенные сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Хочу сделать так чтобы бот телеграмм сохранял определенные сообщения в файл txt.К примеру участник группы написал свою дату рождения и надо чтобы это автомотически сохранилось в файл и потом я ввёл команду и из этого файла взялись дни рождения и желательно написались в чате. Сам как сделать догадаться не могу. Прошу момочь если это возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал вот как:
Скажем, есть команда /birthday, человек вводит свой ДР в формате: день/месяц, и это сохраняется в txt вместе с именем пользователя.
Код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['birthday']) #Добавление дней рождений (/birthday {дата})
async def birthday(message: types.Message):
    arg=message.get_args()
    with open('birthday.txt', 'a+') as file: #добавляем в файл в формате: {Имя} | {дата}
        file.write(f'{message.from_user.first_name} | {arg}') # (имя берется из телеграма)
    await message.answer('Готово!')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['get']) #Выгрузка списка дней рождений (/get)
async def getbd(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_document(types.InputFile('birthday.txt'))
```

Comment: P.S. Плюсик был бы приятен, если помог <3

Answer (score 0):

Вот маленький пример использую **аиограм** тут я сохраняю всё что отправить пользователь в **тхт** файле в **телеботе** почти тоже самое если ты пишешь бота в **телеботе** отпиши напишу маленький примерный код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]